# Can I run flutter without xcode on mac?

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, dart

I want to run flutter without Xcode on mac with just an android studio. Any dependencies I should install cause right now I only have installed flutter, android studio. I installed xcode 10 but flutter gave warning about versions, also it said no device connected even though my iOS simulator was running.

I am unable to run homebrew as well?

Comment: you can, but you can't built for IOS without xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Without xcode you will not be able to build a flutter app that runs on an iOS simulator or device as xcode is what builds for the iOS platform. You will be able to run it on an android emulator that you configure and launch from within Android Studio, and that will work regardless of if xcode is installed.

Homebrew not running looks like a seperate issue and probably a path problem.

Comment: How can I fix path for homebrew? and also if I install the xcode simulator not the whole xcode and run  from android studio is that ok?

Comment: Even if you install the xcode simulator you still cant run a flutter app on it without xcode to build the app for iOS.

Comment: As for the homebrew issue it could be a lot of things, are you trying to run it within an IDE's terminal like vscode or your mac's terminal? You have to fix the path manually in vscode for it to find certain programs

Comment: but the android simulator doesn't work I am using high seirra and it doesn't open says no device found and i am running using mac terminal

Comment: I can but only xcode 10 and apparently flutter requires minimum of xcode 12 the android emulator displays something like this and is just stuck on black screen

```Do you want to save the current state for the next quick boot?

Note: Saving the snapshot may take longer because free RAM is low.```

Comment: Are you able to update to a later version of macOS other than High Sierra? Also if you are running into ram issues just running an emulator you will probably have trouble building and running a flutter app on top of it

Comment: If it would let you get a newer version of xcode it could solve your problem for not being able to run a simulator. As for why your android emulator is having problems I am not sure, but the place for those kinds of troubleshooting is a different question/forum

Comment: It is my first day I decided to learn flutter maybe I should switch I guess to something else

Comment: I mean flutter is probably the best mobile development solution right now, you just need to have a machine able to run all the required tools for mobile development. The same would be true for most other technologies, xcode for iOS and android SDK to build for android

Comment: The simulators not running is a seperate issue from Flutter

Comment: I understand mate I will look into it, one question 
If I do windows in my mac via vm and than run flutter better?

Comment: That might help with the android problem but would also have a considerable performance impact since you would be running another OS. I would try destroying the android simular and reinstalling android and the android SDK to see if that helps first